# Spring web app start up - @ComponentScan - app context and web context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, default, startup, component-scan

Our Spring MVC web app is trying to follow the recommended style. It uses AppContext (`ContextLoaderListener`) to store the DAO's and Services. It uses WebAppContext (`DispatcherServlet`) to store Controllers.

The DAO objects are getting into **both** the AppContext and the WebAppContext. I don't understand why.

The AppContext config is supposed to load everything except the Controllers (and a class that loads code tables into the ServletContext):

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = {"blah"},
  excludeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = {Controller.class}),
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = LoadOnStartup.class) 
  } 
)
public class SpringRootConfiguration {
```

and the web part is supposed to load the Controllers only:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(
 basePackages = {"blah"},
 includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes={Controller.class})
)
public class SpringWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

(The above classes are in a separate package that is a sibling to 'blah'; there's no self-scanning going on).

Of course, the Controllers reference DAO objects. In the Controller, those DAO objects are `@Autowired`.

My expectation was that those `@Autowired` DAO objects are retrieved from the AppContext, and not created a second time, and placed in the WebAppContext. But I think they are being created a second time. For example, this line appears twice in the log, once for AppContext, and once for WebAppContext:

```
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'labelDao'
```

Am I missing something?

It's as if the parent-child relation between the root context and the web context is missing.

Comment: You are missing `useDefaultFilters=false` on the `SpringWebConfiguration`. Including something doesn't automatically exclude everything else, i.e. the defaults.

Comment: I am not at expert in Spring (not even close) but... I believe that beans/@Component/@Repository are singletons by default. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039901/spring-repository-best-practices

Comment: @M. Deinum - that's the fix... If you add an answer (as opposed to a comment), I will accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an `include` filter that doesn't automatically mean that the defaults are disabled. By default `@ComponentScan` will detect all `@Component` classes, regardless of what yu specify by the `include`. So if you want to explicitly to control which annotations to scan you first have to disable the defaults. To do set the `useDefaultFilters` attribute of `@ComponentScan` to `false`.

```
@ComponentScan(
 basePackages = {"blah"},
 useDefaultFilters=false,
 includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes={Controller.class})
)
```

Now it will only detect `@Controller` annotated beans.